# export all product fields with custom options

Tags: magento-1.9, importexport

I need to import products in **Magento 1.9** through **`.csv`**

Simple products which I need to import all have custom options.

Can you tell me where should I find the structure of the **`csv`** with the correct fields to be filled?

Answer (score 0):

Add a **new simple product** and then go to **setting** and find **export/import setting** then export your products into **CSV** then you will get structures.

Answer (score 0):

am I looking for a method (script type) that exports all the values ​​of the Custom Options (if active in simple products)? The subsequent import must also be foreseen. Here is what I need: 1-Bulk export all the values ​​of the customized options (of the whole magento catalog). For example export CSV files. 2-Translate and / or modify them (even just a few) 3-Re-import them in bulk. Some idea? Thank you very much